# do you have to do define-key -> nil & define-key -> function every time?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm not sure if this is package-specific (example here is `olivetti-mode`), but when I try to "remap" with statement:

`(define-key olivetti-mode-map (kbd "<f7> ]") 'olivetti-shrink)` (for some reason you have also wrap this in `eval-after-load`, but omitted here)

The old keybinding for the function `olivetti-shrink` (`C-c ]`) stays in place, so that I now get two keybindings for the same function. I only want the new key-binding. As a general rule, do you have to map to `nil` **whenever** you want to change the key binding:

```
(define-key some-mode-map (kbd "old-key") nil)
(define-key some-mode-map (kbd "new-key") function)
```

I'm wondering if this is really so.

Answer?:
According to this [tutorial](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/09/25/removing-key-bindings-from-minor-mode-keymaps/) the answer is YES: you have to do it every time.
One workaround is to use `use-package` which allows you to configure a bunch of options after loading, including keybindings.

Comment: Drew has mentioned it in his answer, but in Emacs the term "remap" has a particular meaning which is distinctly different to what you are doing here.

Comment: Also FYI the "for some reason" regarding `eval-after-load` is that you can't make changes to a keymap that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I don't understand how `use-package` is a workaround, you would still have to unbind the old key if you don't want it to do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. A given command can have multiple bindings in the same map.

You are asking to add a key binding for the command, and you are asking to remove a key binding for the command.

You say "*every time*", but it is not that common to want to replace a key binding with another.  In any case, if you want to do that a lot you can easily define a macro that does it: carries out a replacement by an addition and a deletion.

(On the other hand, it is common to want to *replace the command* that is bound to a given key by another command. For that Emacs lets you either (1) use `[remap COMMAND]` in `define-key` or `global-set-key` or (2) use `substitute-key-definition`.)